# WEEK_OF_YEAR mismacthing in JAVA and MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, date, calendar

I am executing the below Java code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

**output:**

> 28
>
> Fri Jul 08 08:56:04 BST 2016

Below is the command I executed in MYSQL:

```
select week(CURDATE()), CURDATE();
```

**Output:**

> 27   2016-07-08

How to sync the both the week of the year value? I tried `week(CURDATE(),0)` still same result, without `TimeZone` also tried but getting same result.

Comment: FYI: The definition of `Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR` varies by locale. Avoid that class entirely; now supplanted by *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the "first week in a year" is an abitrary one. You need to find out what the MySQL definition being used is and make Java match it, or find out what the default Java definition is and make MySQL match it.

On the Java side, it will be influenced by [Calendar#setFirstDayOfWeek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek-int-) and [Calendar#setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek-int-) (possibly others, check the `Calendar` docs).

Comment: I need generic way of solution

Comment: @Rajesh: That **is** a generic solution: Ensure that the rules match between the two systems. (And "I need" is a very poor way to ask for help.)

Comment: Thank you. @T.J.Crowder . I am using YEARWEEK() in MySQL with default mode.
So what would be the Java equivalent ? I am not able to figure it out. Kindly help.